# Javascript- Add row dynamically contain dropbox and formula

Tags: javascript

I have a table consist of 5 column: Code, Name, Qty, Price, and Total.

Code contain a dropbox menu which dynamically retrieve from another table. If user click the dropbox and select a code, name of the item will appear automatically in Name column.

For Total column, the value will appear from multiplying Qty and Price. The multiply script I used is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function multiply()
    {
    a=Number(document.calculator.qty.value);
    b=Number(document.calculator.price.value);
    c=a*b;
    document.calculator.total.value=c;
    }
</script>
```

My code for the table as below:

```
    <table id="theTable" border="1">
        <script>
           var maxID = 0;
           function getTemplateRow() {
           var x = document.getElementById("templateRow").cloneNode(true);
           x.id = "";
           x.style.display = "";
           x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace(/{id}/, ++maxID);
           return x;
           }
           function addRow() {
           var t = document.getElementById("theTable");
           var rows = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
           var r = rows[rows.length - 1];
           r.parentNode.insertBefore(getTemplateRow(), r);
           }
        </script>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Code </th>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> Qty </th>
            <th> Price </th>
            <th> Total </th>
        <tr> 
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr id="templateRow">
            <td type="text" name="code" id="code"/readonly>
                <?php  
                mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
                mysql_select_db("inventory");  
                $result = mysql_query("select * from input_code_data");  
                $jsArray = "var code = new Array();\n";  
                echo '<select name="code" onchange="changeValue(this.value)">';  
                echo '<option></option>';  
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
                echo '<option value="' . $row['code'] . '">' . $row['code'] . '</option>';  
                $jsArray .= "code['" . $row['code'] . "'] = {name:'" . addslashes($row['name']) . "',desc:'".addslashes($row['name'])."'};\n";  
                } 
                echo '</select>';  
                ?>  
            </td>

            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"/readonly>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    <?php echo $jsArray; ?>
                    function changeValue(id){
                    document.getElementById('code').value = code[id].name;
                    document.getElementById('name').value = code[id].desc;
                    };
                </script>
            </td>   

            <td><input type="text" name="qty"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total" /readonly><INPUT type="button" value="Click" onclick="javascript:multiply();"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>        
    </table>
    <INPUT type='button' value='+' onclick="addRow('theTable')" />
```

If I click add row, then a new row will appear and the format is right. The problem is, when I select a code (from the dropbox) in second row, the name appear in the first row instead, not in the second row. Another problem, `Click` button for multiply isn't working in the second row.

Would anybody tell me how I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the output of the template row please once it has been rendered.

Comment: It's just building options for the `select` input and the corresponding php `$jsArray` which looks to be attempting to build some sort of amalgamated Array/Object to be used below to get a handle on elements using the `changeValue` function I believe.

Comment: @CodingYoshi you can see it here http://i68.tinypic.com/2up2xj6.jpg

Comment: I mean the generated HTML. Use F12 on the browser and then search for your template row and show me the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `changeValue(id)` function is being called with the select field's value, not the row Id. Additionally, you're getting element by static id's instead of passing them in. HTML assumes that an Id will only appear once per page, you're breaking that so it always returns the first match.

---

EDIT for some example code:

This deals with some of the issues (if I'm understanding you properly). You might find the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) helpful around how ids and other selectors work.

`multiply` suffers from the same issues as your original code, but you should be able to figure it out based on what is below:

```
<table id="theTable" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Code </th>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> Qty </th>
            <th> Price </th>
            <th> Total </th>
        <tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="templateRow" id="invoice-line-1">
            <td class="code">
                <select onchange="changeValue(this.value, 'invoice-line-1')">
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <!-- etc. -->
                </select>
                <span></span>
            </td>
            <td class="name"></td>   
            <td><input type="text" name="qty"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="total" /readonly>
                <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="javascript:multiply();">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>        
</table>
<input type='button' value='+' onclick="addRow('theTable')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var codes = {
            "1": {value: 1, name: "Option 1"},
            "2": {value: 2, name: "Option 2"},
            // etc.
        },
        numRows = 1;

    function changeValue(value, id){
        document.querySelector('#' + id + ' td.name').innerHTML = codes[value].name;
        document.querySelector('#' + id + ' td.code > span').innerHTML = code[value].value;
    };

    function addRow() {
        var newRow = document.getElementById("invoice-line-1").cloneNode(true),
        table = document.querySelector("#theTable > tbody");
        newRow.id = "invoice-line-" + (numRows = numRows + 1);
        table.appendChild(rewRow);
        document.querySelector("#invoice-line-" + numRows + " .code > select").setAttribute('onchange', "changeValue(this.value, 'invoice-line-" + numRows + "')");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What should I do to fix it? Could you please give me the detail?

Comment: Is the basic issue that you want to add a row to your table and populate some values when the user changes the select?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to make an invoice page where user can add multiple item in a single invoice.